# Is the sum of random numbers of random variables Gaussian?

Tags: gaussian, probability-density, probability-theory

In random service systems, we will encounter such problems. A random service system comes to ν customers at a certain time, each customer receives a service time of ζi, and the random service time is independent of ν, then the total service time provided by the system is: Sν=ζ1 +ζ2+……ζν . If ζ1, ζ2...ζν are independent and identically distributed, and is also a Gaussian distribution. v is a uniform distribution, is the total time Sν a Gaussian distribution?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO, yes i.i.d will be a normal distribution with the resulting mean being the sum of means and the variance being the sum of variances. But, there are some assumptions. There are more details with respect to the answer here[[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables#:~:text=Independent%20random%20variables,-Let%20X%20and&text=This%20means%20that%20the%20sum,squares%20of%20the%20standard%20deviations).):

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the a random variable `Z` equal to a sum of `n` independent random variables `Xi`, each of which is drawn from a Gaussian distribution, not necessarily the same one, will have a Gaussian distribution:
if `Xi ~ N(ui, si**2)`, where `ui` is the mean value for Gaussian distribution `N(...)`, and `si` is its standard deviation, then `Z` has this distribution

```
Z ~ N(U, S**2)
```

where `U = u1 + ... + un`, `S**2 = s1**2 + ... sn**2`
Check [Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) for details. It states that your `Xi` are not Gaussian RV, but have other distribution, the total `Z` will still approach the Gaussian distribution if `n` is large (many `Xi`).

Answer (score 0):

This does not really work, as if service times are normally distributed then there is positive probability that they are negative, which does not make much sense.  But if the mean is many times the standard deviation then this becomes highly unlikely.

Essentially the answer is no: you end up with a mixture distribution as a result of the random number of terms in the sum.

Since this is a computing site rather than a statistics site, here are a million simulations of the sum in R, with μ=5, σ=1, and ν uniformly distributed on the values {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}:

```
set.seed(2023)
sumnormals <- function(mu, sigma, maxnu){
  sum(rnorm(sample(maxnu,1), mu, sigma))
  }
sims <- replicate(10^6, sumnormals(5, 1, 7))
plot(density(sims))
```

shown a density plot which is clearly not bell-shaped:

[image]